# Puzzling dictionary matching problem

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I've been stuck on this problem for a while and I am hoping someone can help. I am trying to iterate through a column, row[1] in a csv file called transcripts_test.csv and for each string in row[1] match the same string in a dictionary I created called OCR_dict from another csv file called coors_test.csv.

transcripts_test.csv contains:

```
ENST00000347869,chr3,50126341,50156454,1    
ENST00000452166,chr14,21679063,21737583,2  
ENST00000452166,chr14,21679063,21737583,2
```

coors_test.csv contains:

```
chr3,141030221,141031065,Valid_10009,1000,+  
chr6,141030221,141031065,Valid_10005,1000,+  
chr14,141047080,141047610,Valid_10006,1000,+
```

This is my code:

```
import csv

with open('coors_test.csv', mode='r') as coors_infile:
    coors_reader = csv.reader(coors_infile)
    for row in coors_reader:
            chromo = row[0]
            start = row[1]
            end = row[2]
            coordinates_list = [chromo,start,end]   
            OCR_dict = {row[3]:coordinates_list}
            for keys,values in OCR_dict.items():
                OCR_chromosome = values[0]
    with open('transcripts_test.csv', mode='r') as transcripts_infile:
        transcripts_reader = csv.reader(transcripts_infile)
        for row in transcripts_reader:
            transcript_chromosome = row[1]
            if transcript_chromosome == OCR_chromosome:
                print(transcript_chromosome, keys, OCR_chromosome)
```

When I execute the code above, the output I get is:

```
chr14 Valid_10006 chr14  
chr14 Valid_10006 chr14
```

The output I am looking for is:

```
chr3 Valid_10009 chr3  
chr14 Valid_10006 chr14  
chr14 Valid_10006 chr14
```

Why doesn't my code match and print `chr3 Valid_10009 chr3`? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not what you want:

```
        coordinates_list = [chromo,start,end]   
        OCR_dict = {row[3]:coordinates_list}
        for keys,values in OCR_dict.items():
            OCR_chromosome = values[0]
```

it creates a **new** dict in every iteration and that dict just has a single key. Then you loop over that one item and change a local variable ...

What you want is probably more like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
OCR_dict = defaultdict(list)

with open('coors_test.csv', mode='r') as coors_infile:
    coors_reader = csv.reader(coors_infile)
    for row in coors_reader:
        chromo = row[0]
        start = row[1]
        end = row[2] 
        # OCR_dict is a mapping `chromo -> [(start,end), (start,end), ...]`
        OCR_dict[chromo].append((start,end))

with open('transcripts_test.csv', mode='r') as transcripts_infile:
    transcripts_reader = csv.reader(transcripts_infile)
    for row in transcripts_reader:
        transcript_chromosome = row[1]
        # look that chromosome up in the dict and print it if it exists
        if transcript_chromosome in OCR_dict:
            print(transcript_chromosome, OCR_dict[transcript_chromosome])
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think I understand what you are saying. I tried running the above code you provided, but nothing prints. Any idea what could be the problem. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I think the problem is that the values in the dictionary are a list of three items. I don't think :wtranscript_chromosome can match the items in the list.

Comment: @dr.bunsen: You find items by their key, not value. If you want to match anything in a dict you have to use it as the key. But I think it's right, `chr3` etc looks like the key to match.

Comment: I sincerely appreciate your help Jochen. I think my main problem is that I do not understand how to access the values within the dictionary. I need to do a number of manipulations with the dictionary values individually. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

`OCR_chromosome` is set to the last value of `chromo` that's encountered.  In other words, `OCR_chromosome` will be the first value in the last row of coors_test.csv.  chr14 will be the only value that can be matched.  I'm not positive what exactly you're going for, but this should produce the `chromo` values you're looking for:

```
import csv

chromos = set()
with open('coors_test.csv', mode='r') as coors_infile:
    for row in csv.reader(coors_infile):
            chromo = row[0]
            chromos.add(chromo)
    with open('transcripts_test.csv', mode='r') as transcripts_infile:
        for row in csv.reader(transcripts_infile):
            transcript_chromosome = row[1]
            if transcript_chromosome in chromos:
                print transcript_chromosome
```